# Neural Network Mining Model Fails with Nested Mining Structure

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a nested mining structure I am attempting to model for predictive analysis. Without fail, adding a "Microsoft Neural Network" model to my models causes the following two errors, after which the processing of the models ceases:

> Internal error: An unexpected exception occurred.
>
> Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

All of my other models work fine, it only happens when I add the NN.

I've tried creating much simpler nested structures and get the same result. I've also tried processing the model directly from SSMS, but I don't get any more information. Looking around through the logs I could find was not fruitful. I can't seem to find where exactly more verbose error reporting would be found, if it exists.

Is the Neural Network model simply not supported with nested structures? Some insight into how to find more details about these errors would be useful.

I'm using SQL Server and SSAS 2019.

**Edit**

Here's what my structure looks like:

[image]

Here's what the model setup looks like (apriori works fine):

[image]

This is what happens when I try to process the model:

[image]

If I launch with debugger I get this:

[image]
[image]

**Edit: view details have no further info:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to run the debugger on this?

Comment: @JWeezy Thanks for the reply -- debugging yields the same error messages. It happens during deployment, whatever that's worth

Comment: Can you post some screenshots so we can see what we are dealing with?

Comment: @JWeezy Sure, see above edits

Comment: How inputs and outputs are formatted ?

Comment: @razimbres You mean the data types? I just used the suggested types unless, for example, something incorrectly classified as continuous instead of a bool. But again, other model types haven't had any problems with the inputs/outputs

Comment: @Daniel in Process progress , click on the first error then click on "View details" and paste it here m if it has interesting information

Comment: @eshirvana Unfortunately no further details. Updated with screens